# What is a $G$-admissible subgroup?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, definition

I'm reading [$1$] and cannot find the the definition for "$G$-admissible subgroup" where $G$ is a finite $p$-group and $p$ is a prime. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

**Reference**

[1] Ja. G. Berkovic, *A generalization of the theorems of Hall and Blackburn and their applications to nonregular p-groups*, Math.USSR IZvestija, 5(1971), 829-832.

Edit:
The first time this term appears:
Let the $p$-group $G$ be endowed with a $p$-group of operators $A$ and let $W$ be some group-theoretic property. Even if $G$ contains a normal $W$-subgroup, it doesn't necessarily contain a normal $A$-admissible $W$-subgroup.

Hope this can facilitate.

Comment: You need to provide more context. Your post is incomprehensible as it stands, and most people reading this will not be familiar with the paper by Berkovich. I would guess that $G$ is acting on some other group $X$, and a $G$-admissible subgroup of $X$ is a subgroup that is stabilized by $G$ under this action.

Comment: OK, so an $A$-admissible $W$-subgroup is a subgroup of $G$ with the property $W$ that is stabilized under the action of $A$.